# Auto hide/show List Section header in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I make a list in SwiftUI with header like following, how to make the header auto hide when I scroll up and comeback when scroll down?

```
    List{
        Section(header: headerView){
            ForEach(customers.filter{
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```